# Why is the Eloquent model "booted" method not firing on Laravel 7.x?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this simple code on an Eloquent model to fire during the model `creating` event to auto-create a slug for the model.

```php
    use Illuminate\Support\Str; 

    ...

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::creating(function (self $model) {
            if (!$model->slug) {
                $model->slug = Str::slug($model->title);
            }
        });
    }
```

It's not firing when it's up on our staging site, and I have literally no idea why. It works fine locally. I'm just getting `General error: 1364 Field 'slug' doesn't have a default value...` when trying to create a new model.

When I change it to this, it works as expected:

```php
    use Illuminate\Support\Str; 

    ...

    protected static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::creating(function (self $model) {
            if (!$model->slug) {
                $model->slug = Str::slug($model->title);
            }
        });
    }
```

However, this is a Laravel 7.x install so surely the `booted` method should work?

Does anyone know of a reason why `booted` would not be firing while `boot` works?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden -Thanks, but  I'm using the slug as the routeKeyName and also use it for queries elsewhere, so a mutator doesn't work for that